# Decimal value to date and time in Progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I would like to know how to convert a decimal value to date and time.

DEFINE VARIABLE tt_decimal AS DECIMAL INIT "2,459,040.7355" .

DEFINE VARIABLE tt_date AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE tt_time AS CHARACTER.

How to convert the above tt_decimal to tt_date and tt_time.

Comment: Where does the `tt_decimal` value come from? What does the `.7355` part mean? Most number representations of dates/times in ABL are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct conversion.

Some old applications that pre-date the DATETIME datatype have used various conventions to build their own.  (This was all 20+ years ago - modern code uses the builtin DATETIME datatype.) Sometimes they stuffed the date into the integer side and the time into the decimal side (usually by dividing time in seconds by 100,000).  But there is nothing guaranteeing that that approach has been taken with your data. In fact your "sample code" strongly suggests that you might have the DATETIME in a string since you have shown an initial value as a character string rather than a decimal. You would need to determine what has really been done with your data.

If you are building something new, rather than integrating with existing legacy code you should use DATETIME or DATETIME-TZ.  Not DECIMAL or CHARACTER.

If you have legacy code using a DECIMAL data type and the date is the integer portion and the time is the decimal portion as described above then you could convert it like this:

```
function decimal2datetime return datetime ( input decimalDT as decimal ):

  define variable d as date    no-undo.
  define variable t as integer no-undo.

  define variable i as integer no-undo.
  define variable x as decimal no-undo.

  i = truncate( decimalDT, 0 ).    /* we will presume that the integer portion is a date */
  x = ( decimalDT - i ).           /* and that the decimal portion is time in seconds   */

  d = date( i ).                   /* convert an integer to a date using the default Progress epoch                           */
  t = 100000 * x.                  /* assuming that the time in seconds was converted to a decimal via division by 100,000 */

  return datetime( d, t * 1000 ).  /* the time parameter to datetime() is specified in milliseconds.                              */

end.


display decimal2datetime( 2459040.7355 ).
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for the input. I created 2 functions reference to the above ( decimalt2date and decimal2time).
It worked fine.